# undefined method `mechanism=' for ActiveSupport::Dependencies:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: dependencies, activesupport

I have a problem while generating a controller in rails 7.0.0

When I run the command

```
rails g controller Home index
```

It gives me the following error.

```
/home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:103:in `block in preload': undefined method `mechanism=' for ActiveSupport::Dependencies:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    from /home/dev/project/spousal/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.3/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:106:in `preload'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>
```

I have googled but found no solution. So what's the reason for this error?

Answer (score 47):

I recently upgraded an to Rails 7.0.1 and I ran into this same issue. I saw this same error when trying to run `rails console`.

I got past it when I removed `spring-watcher-listen` from the Gemfile (because it was preventing `spring` from updating past `2.x`) and then bumped `spring` to `3.0.0` in the Gemfile. Then I ran `bundle` and `rails console` worked again.

This seems like a bump we have to overcome in upgrading Rails as noted in [this article under "6. Notable Changes"](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/rails/upgrades/upgrade-rails-6-1-to-7-0.html).

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks!

Comment: You can now use `spring-watcher-listen` version `2.1.0` with `spring >= 4`

Answer (score 1):

same here, on `rails g migration ..`. after updating to rails-7.0.4. allthough i had in my gemfile `gem "spring"` and ran `bundle update`, spring ran on 2.x.. changed it in Gemfile to `gem 'spring', '~> 4.1'` ran bundle and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was this gem:
`gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'`

I was using it as well, after removing it from Gemfile I could `bundle update spring`, so the `rails c` went working back.

Answer (score -2):

Faced this issue after updating a rails 6 application to rails 7.
I tried to execute the `rails g model User` command.

I solved it by recreating the project with rails 7 directly.

If you have an existing project that you upgraded to rails 7 you cant apply this solution. Better refer the official conversion [rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org)